# How to convert string to long?

Tags: convert

There is `String.toInt()`, but no `String.toLong()` or the many other variations. Do I have to resort to `atol(String.c_str())` or is there a better way to convert a `String` to a long?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `atol(String.c_str())` looks OK to me. If there was a `String.toLong()` it would be written that way anyway.

In fact, looking at the code for `String.toInt()` that's exactly what it does:

```
long String::toInt(void) const
{
    if (buffer) return atol(buffer);
    return 0;
}
```

So the answer is: use `String.toInt()`.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why they didn't just call it `toLong()`??

Answer (score 1):

So the answer is: use String.toInt().

Probably not, as this is the definition of a String method:

long String::toInt(void) const

The real work is:

atol(buffer);

ASCII to long.